# Android use Host GPU wraps screen and puts menu bar on top?

Tags: android, user-interface, gpu, android-virtual-device

After I installed HAXM and enabled HOST GPU, my screen for my virtual machine looks a bit off. The physical menu bar is now on the top, and to click any button you have to hover approx 10px above the button. So to click the top HOME button, i have to click 10px above the BOTTOM of the screen because the screen seems to be wrapped. Any help?

[image]

Comment: have you solved this mystery yet?

Comment: I am also having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try not to create it from snapshot. If it doesn't help re-create it.
This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39026) hasn't been fixed yet

Answer (score -1):

## androidprotip : Configuring an AVD to use graphics acceleration

You need Android SDK Tools rev 17 or higher, then start by creating a new AVD with the target value of Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15), using SDK rev 3 and System Image rev 2 (or higher).

If you want to have graphics acceleration enabled by default for this AVD, in the Hardware section of the AVD configuration, click New, select GPU emulation and set the value to Yes.

You need to make sure to hit enter when you change the value in the list before closing the dialog.

You can also turn on graphics acceleration at run time:
emulator -avd  -gpu on